# How to remove Item from the standard toolbar or ribbon control of DotSpatial

Tags: dotspatial

I would like to remove the Add Layer and Remove Layer buttons from standard toolbar which comes from SpatialToolStripPanel. With the code below, I could remove Pan and Select buttons.

```
  public Form1()
    {
                InitializeComponent();
                appManager1.LoadExtensions();
                appManager1.HeaderControl.Remove("Pan");
                appManager1.HeaderControl.Remove("Select");
    }
```

However, I cannot remove Add Layer and Remove Layer buttons with below code

```
            appManager1.HeaderControl.Remove("Add_Layer");
            appManager1.HeaderControl.Remove("Remove_Layer");
```